# Applying binomial expansion and using algebra to find the value of $a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Q) In the expansion of
$f(x)=(1 + ax)^4 (1 + bx)^5$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers,
the coefficient of $x^2$ is 66.
Evaluate $a+b$.

My working:

After expanding the expression I simplified it and got

$5b^2+10ab+3a^2=33$

After further simplification, I managed to get

$5(a+b)^2-2a^2=33$

but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I agree with your working, and I'm also not sure what to do next. Hmm....

Comment: Note that $1\leq a\leq a+b$ so $3a^2 \leq 5(a+b)^2-2a^2\leq 33$. Thus $1\leq a\leq 3$. Now, I assume you can check the three values of $a$.

Comment: Oh, they're positive integers. That narrows it down. I didn't read that part properly the first time round.

Comment: @Kapil  according to your way , no integral values satisfy this .

Answer (score 3):

Your result is correct.

If $a,b\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ then we can write,

$$\begin{align}&5b^2+3a^2≥2\sqrt {15}ab\\
\implies &5b^2+3a^2+10ab≥ab \left(10+2\sqrt {15}\right)\\
\implies &33≥\left(10+2\sqrt {15}\right)ab\\
\implies &ab≤\frac{33}{10+2\sqrt {15}}<2\\
\implies &a=b=1.\end{align}$$

This means, the solution doesn't exist.